# Problem installing nodemon globally on macOS Mojave

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm, nodemon

In the Visual Studio Code terminal I issue to following command:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

The result in terminal is:

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ilkin/.npm/_logs/2020-08-30T16_39_29_236Z-debug.log
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This means that you do not have root privileges / are not a superuser. You have two ways to solve this.

- Use `sudo` before the command - this will usually then ask for credentials and run the command without a problem (hopefully)
- Run `sudo -s` to automatically run commands with sudo every time in the current terminal window (will deactivate once the terminal has been closed)
- Run `sudo su` which will make the computer think that the current terminal window has been opened by a root user (again will deactivate once current window has been closed)

Answer (score 0):

Use sudo before installing, it will ask for credentials enter it and done

```
sudo npm i - g nodemon
```

Comment: First thank you. I use vs code terminal to install nodemon. can I use sudo for vs code terminal?

Comment: terminal will behave same even in vs code